# Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPositionAsync returns too many symbols

Tags: c#, intellisense, roslyn

Here is the C# code I am trying to investigate using Roslyn:

```
using System;
namespace TEST
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

I call

```
I call IEnumerable<ISymbol> symbols = Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPositionAsync(semanticModel,130, TheWorkspace).Result;
```

Note - character 130 is the first 'i' within WriteLine.

I expected to obtain smth similar to the VS intellisense: a list of several options including Write and WriteLine. Instead I am getting a list of 222 symbols including some namespace etc. I get similar results if I use SemanticModel.LookupSymbol method.

Here is my full code:

```
    public class IntellisenseVM
{ 
    private string _text = 
@"using System;
namespace TEST
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
        }
    }
}";
    const string DOC_NAME = "MyDoc.cs";

    public AdhocWorkspace TheWorkspace { get; set; }

    public IntellisenseVM()
    {
        TheWorkspace = new AdhocWorkspace();

        string projName = "NewProject";

        ProjectId projId = ProjectId.CreateNewId();

        VersionStamp versionStamp = VersionStamp.Create();

        ProjectInfo projInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(projId, versionStamp, projName, projName, LanguageNames.CSharp);


        SourceText sourceText = SourceText.From(_text);

        projInfo = projInfo.WithMetadataReferences
        (
            new MetadataReference[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
            }
        );

        TheWorkspace.AddProject(projInfo);


        Document doc = 
            TheWorkspace.AddDocument(this.TheWorkspace.CurrentSolution.ProjectIds[0], "MyDoc.cs", sourceText);

        SemanticModel semanticModel = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

        IEnumerable<Diagnostic> diagnostics = semanticModel.GetDiagnostics();
        IEnumerable<ISymbol> symbols = 
            Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPositionAsync(semanticModel, 130, TheWorkspace).Result;
    }
}
```

BTW, I checked the diagnostics in the debugger and it is empty (so no compilation errors).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do we work better if you pass the position right after the .?

Comment: Yes, now I know that - after spending a couple of days...

Comment: If that's the correct answer, you can answer your own question. You might also want to file a bug [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) as I'm not sure that's intended behavior.

Comment: Will try to do it on Sunday. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you need to pass an offset to the position after the period (not to the position of the period) in order to get correct result. In any case, as I figured out, it is much better to use the CompletionService that was made public eventually in Roslyn-master branch on the GitHub or in the forthcoming Roslyn update.